# PHP Dynamic Calculations

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I have an HTML form that displays a list of pricing options called back from information from my database, I have created some functions to use this information as calculations to populate the rest of the form. Although I would like for the user to be able to change the values and the calculations to update with this but I can't seem to get that to work!

This is my HTML form code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="totalprice">Total Price</label>
    <input class="input" name="totalprice" type="text" id="totalprice" value="<?php echo $total_price; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="rrp">RRP</label>
    <input class="input" name="rrp" type="text" id="rrp"  value="<?php echo $rrp_price; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="delivery">Delivery</label>
    <input class="input" name="delivery" type="text"  id="delivery" value="<?php echo $delivery; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="rfl">RFL</label>
    <input class="input" name="rfl" type="text"  id="rfl" value="<?php echo $rfl; ?>">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="netprice">Nett Price</label>
    <input class="input" name="netprice" type="text"  id="netprice" value="<?php echo $net_price; ?>">
</div>
</div>
```

and this is my PHP code to get the values and do the calculations

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT created_by, accessories, customer_ID, total_price, rrp FROM new_quote WHERE quote_ID = '$quote_ID'");
$data = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$sales_person = $data[0];
$accessories = $data[1];
$customer_ID = $data[2];
$total_price = str_replace('£', '', $data[3]);
$rrp_price = $data[4];

$rrp_price2 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $rrp_price); 
$rrp_price = substr($rrp_price2, 3);

$total_price2 = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $total_price);
$total_price = substr($total_price2, 3);

$rfl = $total_price - $rrp_price - $delivery - $care_products;

$net_price = ($total_price - $rfl) / 1.2;

$gr_profit = ($net_price * 0.11) + 500;

$po_profit = ($net_price * 0.03);
```

Comment: So where's your question...? Where's the point you stuck?

Comment: How do I get it to update the calculation when the text boxes are changed with values cause at the minute it only does the calculation with the values that are originally pulled from the database and nothing happens when I change these..?

Comment: Read about "Dealing with forms" at php.net: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: I know how to deal with forms, I have been reading for a while on how to do this and came here to see if someone could help me without being a smart ass. If you don't know the answer then don't comment and stop wasting both our time!

Comment: I don't know where you stuck... I can't see any form dealing things in your code so you probably didn't even know that you have to work with `$_POST` or `$_GET` or maybe even don't know that you have to use a `<form>` tag? So I thought I provide you with those basic information. But if you name me a smart-ass than maybe try it at your own again is the best you can do.

Comment: I have a lot of code on these pages so I didn't feel the need to put it all in, I just highlighted the areas of the topic where I was stuck so people would get the idea of what I was trying to do..

Comment: You have 2 options: 1-use pure javascript and duplicate the code that make the calculations. 2-use javascript and php, split the php calculation into different functions/files/methods, everyone will handle a different field, so you send and ajax to that function/file/method and get the result as json and then set the field value.

Comment: Or use just PHP would be option 3 @sudo.ie

Comment: Just php is not possible, because you want that when a person change one field populate something else. PHP runs on server side, what you need is a client side logic only javascript will do that. Using jquery it could be really simple.

Comment: Thanks @sudo.ie I thought I might need jquery or something else but was hoping not as I haven't used it much. I'll have a look into jquery!

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server-side scripting language, so if you want to do new calculation, you have to call the server again (because there is the place where I see that you do them). If you want to do the calculation without a request to the server, you have to use a client-side language like JavaScript